im having trouble with python variables
import pygame,time
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((512, 488))
player_pos = pygame.Vector2(screen.get_width() / 2, screen.get_height() / 2)
prev_time = time.time()
player_velo_y = 0
player_velo_x = 0
player_gravity = 200
running = True    
import pygame

class player():
    def gravity():
        player_pos.y = player_pos.y + player_velo_y * dt
        player_velo_y = player_velo_y + player_gravity * dt

while running:
    #delta time
    now = time.time()
    dt = now - prev_time
    prev_time = now
    #draw to screen
    player.gravity()
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)

this is a function that handles player gravity, Im trying to slowly increase player velocity while also adding player velocity to the Y coordinate, when i run the program it prints "UnboundLocalError: cannot access local variable 'player_velo_y' where it is not associated with a value"

Please provide a [mcve]. Please also explain what output you were expecting and what output you were seeing (and how it differs from the output you were expecting). your problem description that "python does not seem to like that" doesn't tell us anything useful.

Just add them up without +=. player_pos.y = player_pos.y + player_velo_y * dt and player_velo_y = player_velo_y + player_gravity * dt. Also this is probably a typo: player_pos.y -> player_pos_y

@user24714692 are you just guessing here? Why should that make a difference? Why shouldn't you use +=?  Why do you think player_pos.y is a typo? Seems like a totally reasonable line of code. Of course, it may be. But that is just a wild guess

@user24714692 and perhaps even more importantly, your solution (if the situation is in fact the one you suspect), then using or not using+= will give an UnboundLocal error (after the presumed player_pos.y -> player_pos_y is fixed)

python does not seem to like that? We have no idea what this means. If you're getting an error, or unexpected results, you have to tell us.  Saying "python didn't like it" tells us nothing about the actual problem.

@juanpa.arrivillaga i have made edits to provide more context, hopefully this is appropriate.

@JohnGordon i have made edits to provide more context, hopefully this is appropriate.

When a variable is assigned inside a function, that variable is assumed to be local, even if there is a global variable of the same name.  Put global player_velo_y at the top of the gravity() function to treat it as a global variable.
